# What is the difference between possibleOutboundIpAddresses and outboundIpAddresses field in Azure Resource explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In azure resource explorer, there are two fields that shows up one is `possibleOutBoundIpAddresses` and another is `outboundIpAddresses`. What is the difference between the two? Which property to use to white list the IP addresses for data access?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set of outbound IP addresses for your app changes when you scale your app between the lower tiers (Basic, Standard, and Premium) and the Premium V2 tier.

`outboundIpAddresses` : outbound IP addresses at the current pricing tier

`possibleOutBoundIpAddresses`: all possible outbound IP addresses for your app, regardless of pricing tiers

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-addresses#when-outbound-ips-change).

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for clarification. Can you please cite the source. I searched a lot but I didn't find any official documentation clarifying it?

Comment: Roger. Thanks for the link